# was able to connect to hive db without the need to load HiveDriver class

Tags: java, hive

I was able to connect to hive database and perform query against it without the need to load the org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver? how did this happen?
we know if we want to connect to any database first we need to load the driver using class.forname("fullyqualified driver class name"). but in my case i was able to connect to hive db without writing above code. below is my code.
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"we **know** if we want to connect to any database first we need to load the driver"* -- well, you should definitely update that knowledge...

Excerpts from the official Oracle/Sun documentation:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

> In previous versions of JDBC, to obtain a connection, you first had to
>   initialize your JDBC driver by calling the method `Class.forName`
>   
> ...
>  Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are
>   automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any drivers
>   prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method `Class.forName`)

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

> As part of its initialization, the DriverManager class will attempt to
>   load the driver classes referenced in the `jdbc.drivers` system
>   property. This allows a user to customize the JDBC Drivers used by
>   their applications
> ...
>  The DriverManager methods
>   *getConnection* and *getDrivers* have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers
>   must include the file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. This file
>   contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of
>   java.sql.Driver
> ...
>  Applications no longer need to explictly
>   load JDBC drivers using Class.forName(). Existing programs which
>   currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to
>   work without modification

Comment: thanks samson for waking me up. it's been three years that i have not touched JDBC. :)